# functions not being called in JSFiddle

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle

It seems that none of the functions in this JSFiddle are being called -
http://jsfiddle.net/2x4yt0vb/11/

There are functions for validation and a clear function.  None of the validations are working.  For example if -20 or aaa is entered in the form "Invalid entry" and other error messages should be displayed.  When the Clear button is clicked none of the functionality within the clear() function is firing.  Why aren't these functions working in JSFiddle?

Here is the HTML:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="formulaCtrlr" >
<form name="vm.formContainer.form" autocomplete="off">
                          <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': vm.formContainer.form.FatA.$dirty && vm.formContainer.form.FatA.$invalid}">
                            <label for="FatA" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fat A</label>
                            <input name="FatA" type="text" class="form-control col-sm-10 input-sm" ng-required="true" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" ui-validate="{numberCheck: 'vm.numberCheck($value)', fatRangeCheck: 'vm.fatRangeCheck($value)'}" ng-model="vm.formulaInput.Fats[0]" /><span>%</span>
                            <span class="error" ng-show="vm.formContainer.form.FatA.$dirty && vm.formContainer.form.FatA.$invalid">Invalid entry.</span>
                            <span class="error" ng-show="vm.formContainer.form.FatA.$dirty && vm.formContainer.form.FatA.$error.numberCheck">{{vm.errorMessages.numberCheck}}</span>
                            <span class="error" ng-show="vm.formContainer.form.FatA.$dirty && vm.formContainer.form.FatA.$error.fatRangeCheck">{{vm.errorMessages.fatRangeCheck}}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': vm.formContainer.form.FatB.$dirty && vm.formContainer.form.FatB.$invalid}">
                            <label for="FatB" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fat B</label>
                                <input name="FatB" type="text" class="form-control col-sm-10 input-sm" ng-required="true" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" ui-validate="{numberCheck: 'vm.numberCheck($value)', fatRangeCheck: 'vm.fatRangeCheck($value)'}" ng-model="vm.formulaInput.Fats[1]" /><span>%</span>
                                <span class="error" ng-show="vm.formContainer.form.FatB.$dirty && vm.formContainer.form.FatB.$invalid">Invalid entry.</span>
                                <span class="error" ng-show="vm.formContainer.form.FatB.$dirty && vm.formContainer.form.FatB.$error.numberCheck">{{vm.errorMessages.numberCheck}}</span>
                                <span class="error" ng-show="vm.formContainer.form.FatB.$dirty && vm.formContainer.form.FatB.$error.fatRangeCheck">{{vm.errorMessages.fatRangeCheck}}</span>
                        </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2">
                                <input type="reset" value="Clear" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.clear()" ng-disabled="vm.formContainer.form.$pristine" />
                            </div>                        
</form>
        <div>formula input: {{vm.formulaInput}}</div>
</div>        
</html>
```

Here is the JS/Angular:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller("formulaCtrlr", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            var vm = this;

        vm.formContainer = {
            form: {}
        }

        vm.formulaInput = {};
        vm.formulaInput.Fats = [];

        vm.clear = function () {            
            vm.formulaInput = {};
            vm.formulaInput.Fats = [];
            vm.formContainer.form.$setPristine();
        }

        vm.errorMessages = {
            numberCheck: 'Value must be a number.',
            fatRangeCheck: 'Number must be between 0 and 100.'
        }

        vm.numberCheck = function (value) {
            var result = !(isNaN(parseFloat(value)));
            return result;
            //return !(isNaN(parseFloat(value)));
        }       

        vm.fatRangeCheck = function (value) {
            var result = (value && value > 0.0 && value < 100.0);
            return result;
            //return (value && value > 0.0 && value < 100.0);
        }               

  }]);
```

Comment: `vm` is used as scope for controllerAs syntax. You don't have one in your example. Write it as: `ng-controller="formulaCtrlr as vm"`

Comment: @Aleksey Solovey that made the clear function work but the validation ones are still not working.

Comment: I just pointed out the obvious. Digging more into the issue: you didn't add the `ui.validate` module. Add the script and extend the main module with an injection: `angular.module('myApp', ['ui.validate'])`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey sorry to be daft, but how do I add the script?

Comment: jsfiddle has a tab (on the left side) **Resources**. Insert a [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular-ui-validate) of the script that you need, then press `(+)`. Or you can do it manually by putting a CDN in `<script>` tags

Comment: @AlekseySolovey thanks very much - it works now!  If you decide to post the above comments in answer format I will be sure to mark it as the answer.